# How can I load a navigation property in an EF 4.0 code first entity collection?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.0 with Code First and I have a Product entity, which has a ProductSpecificationAttributes navigation property. I have a list of Product entities IList products and I would like for all the products in this list to load the ProductSpecificationAttributes, without having to go to the database for every Product in the list. So if I have:

```
IList<Product> products = DbContext.ExecuteStoredProcedureList<Product>(
                "ProductLoadAllPaged", parameters here);
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
IQueryable<Product> query = products.AsQueryable().Include(
x => x.ProductSpecificationAttributes);
```

Is there an automatic way to do that in EF 4.0 Code First without having to query the database for every product, when trying to retrieve its ProductSpecificationAttributes?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see only something like requerying the products by their Id including the navigation collection:

```
IQueryable<Product> query = context.Products
    .Include(p => p.ProductSpecificationAttributes)
    .Where(p => products.Select(p1 => p1.Id).Contains(p.Id));
```

`products.Select(p1 => p1.Id)` is a collection of Ids in memory and the query translates into a SQL `IN` clause. It's only one database roundtrip.